# What are ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion Arguments?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, chart

The function `ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion` has been used on Google Earth Engine document, but it is not clear what are the arguments.

e.g. from the page:

```
var series3 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion(
    collection, 'NDVI', regions, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500, ee.Reducer.mean(), 'label');
```

What is `NDVI` or what is `500`. It seems when it is not specified what they are like so: `band: "NDVI"`, the order of arguments is important.

The reason I am asking is that when I change the order of inputs/arguments, Google Earth Engine throws different errors at me.

What are those arguments? 
How can I specify `crs` and 'crs_transform' and scale in there.

```
Error generating chart: Collection.first: Error in map(ID=64):
Image.reduceRegions: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.


Collection.first: Error in map(ID=64):
Image.reduceRegions: The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the `ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion` reference for the full list of parameters and their descriptions:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ui.chart.image.doyseriesbyregion

Here is the example you provided with arguments given to parameters as a dictionary, which makes it easier to interpret.

```
var series3 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: collection,
  bandName: 'NDVI',
  regions: regions,
  regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 500,
  yearReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  seriesProperty: 'label'
});
```